# SEO check tools don't recognize my title and description

Tags: seo, google, title, seo-audit

[ُThis](http://verifyplus.net) SEO checking site tells me that my site doesn't have title and description tags, but in fact it does. I tried all SEO checking tools and they all report the same issue. What is the problem?

I'm using [Turbogears](http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as my web-framework if it helps.

Comment: You linked your site to the SEO checker, so I removed the link.